# Instantiate a NSManagedObject without saving it

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8

I got a class like :

```
@objc(User)
class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String

    //MARK: - Initialize
    convenience init(id: String,  context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {

        // Create the NSEntityDescription
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: context!)


        // Super init the top init
        self.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)


        // Init class variables
        self.id = id

    }
}
```

I create a new User in a ViewController :

```
managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

var aUser = User(id: "500T", context: managedObjectContext)
```

I have another class "Group" where Group have many Users. To save user I do something like

```
aGroup!.users = NSSet(array: users!)
!managedObjectContext.save
```

I don't want to save all users. How can I instantiate a user without saving it ?

Comment: just don't save. Reset the moc after you are done with the user. Or create a NSManagedObject subclass. I believe you can use them aswel outside of the moc.

Comment: @RMenke I just updated my question because in fact I don't know where to reset because I store all my users in an array then save this NSSet to group using relationship

Comment: Is there someway the users are different? Then you can iterate the array of users and just save the reverse relationship. `aUser.group = aGroup` But to really fix your problem you should create another class with the same value types as the User and create NSManagedObjects only for those that need saving

Comment: @RMenke in fact I add Users to an array to store localy and same Users (copy) to a memory array just to update a tableviewcontroller. The user can be added or deleted from a group. In my local array, I want to store all history of actions (ex: user add to group, user delete from group, user add to group) and in the tableview I only want the last status (ex based on prev example : user add to group).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my answer and add a needSave boolean to the user init. Maybe it's not the best answer but it's working.

```
@objc(User)
class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String

    //MARK: - Initialize
    convenience init(id: String, needSave: Bool,  context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {

        // Create the NSEntityDescription
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: context!)


        if(!needSave) {
            self.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: nil)
        } else {
            self.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        }

        // Init class variables
        self.id = id

    }
}
```

Comment: How the following code will work if the context is nil?
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: context!)

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc(User)
public class User: NSManagedObject {
    
    convenience init(id: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        
        // Create the NSEntityDescription
        let entity = User.entity()
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)


        // Init class variables
        self.id = id
        
    }
}
```