# Swift: NSManagedObject Create an object without saving it in persistence

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I have an object that is registered as entity in my coreData, which inherits from NSManagedObject.

The call to create the object and save it is as follows:

```
let user = User(context: PersistenceService.context)
    user.name = "My name"
    user.address = "My Address"
```

But I do not always want that when I create the object it is recorded in persistence, I want to be able to call it that too:

```
    let user = User()
    user.name = "My name"
    user.address = "My Address"
```

But when I call it this way my crash app.

How can I create several init () according to my needs?

Here is my persistenceService class:

```
class PersistenceService {
// MARK: - Core Data stack

private init() {}

static var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return persistentContainer.viewContext
}

static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Database")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

static func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("SAVED")
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

}

I already look on other people's question, but it does not correspond to what I'm looking for and its in objective C i dont understand objective C i want in swift, I use a sepcified class PersistenceService
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instantiate a NSManagedObject without saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358692/instantiate-a-nsmanagedobject-without-saving-it)

Comment: Argument labels '(entity:, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)' do not match any available overloads. I have change like this:             self.init(context: nil)
but i have this error Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'NSManagedObjectContext'

Comment: You had to use NSManagedObjectContext, however you can create NSManagedObjectContext without persistent store at all (if you don't want to save anything). Or you can use objects in context but never called `save` in this context and again, nor items will be saved.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5

If you use your main context, even without saving, the data is still 'in context'. So if want use core data model without saving it , you need to create a child context and use it on model context.

```
import CoreData

let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

let user = User(context: childContext)
    user.name = "My name"
    user.address = "My Address"
```